# How can I upload a video and make it secure that no one else can play that video even if they know the link of the video?

Tags: magento2.3, secure, video, product-video

Teachers will upload video and students will only be able to watch and download it's tutorial if they pay or purchase that product.

It can have multiple attachments like video streaming and PDF to download

My query is...

**How can I show attachments which are added to the products after student places successful order?**